# Will setting your homepage to "your latest posts" in WordPress hurt Google SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress, homepage

I am struggling with a SEO project because the keywords of this SEO project have no ranking since I finished onsite optimization of 3 months.

I found the website that is using "your latest posts" format in Wordpress instead of "A static page".

Is this setting hurting SEO or Google crawler indexing our website? It it the reason there is no ranking in the search results? Or maybe there is another reason some website keywords will not rank in Google.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you're trying to do. Do you want to rank with the *homepage*? Or do you have *posts and pages* that target the keywords?

**"Static page option" in WordPress** makes sense for some websites and strategies, and of course it depends how well you optimize the static page. You'll have more control over it, so you could craft the perfect landing page with all of your targeted text, the best images, videos, links. This could be hand-picked content by yourself, or you could use plugins to display the most popular content automatically (by views, votes, etc.)

**"Your latest posts" option** is much faster / easier to get started with and it makes sense to use for some websites. The homepage looks fresh, and recent content encourages people to come back later for updates if they like it. This style is more about ranking the posts for your targeted words/phrases.

But you don't have to choose. You can have half static and half latest posts, or any combination really. For example: a section at the top - "News" - with 5-10 of the latest posts automatically placed there, and below that can be all static.

What is your website about and what style makes sense for that? You've seen other websites before, so compare your idea to similar things out there.

You mentioned onsite optimization, but it's going to be difficult to rank for any competitive keywords with just onsite optimization on a 3 month old website. It's probably best to concentrate on creating content right now. Quality content that serves a purpose other than just having keywords in it.

Answer (score 2):

The danger of using latest posts on the home page is duplicate content.   By default, WordPress uses the full text of each of several posts on the home page.   That will cause Google to index your home page, but not index the permalink pages for each individual post.

To combat this, you should edit each post and ensure that you use the [more tag](https://wordpress.com/support/wordpress-editor/blocks/more-block/2/) after the first paragraph in each blog post.   This will cause only a portion of the post to appear on the home page along with a link to "read more." If you show just a portion of posts on the home page, there is no inherent SEO problem with using "latest posts" on the home page.

Even if you use a page as the home page, you should still use the more tag because WordPress has a similar problem with category and tag pages where it by default shows the full text of posts.

Answer (score -1):

Well, in my experience, Google Indexing takes now somewhat long time than before.
With same keyword, it takes more time than 3~6 months than before.
About 1 year ago, google indexing(not appear on 1st page) time was about 2 ~ 3 weeks.
But now, the time is about 2 ~ 3 months.
The cause is incorrect and fuzzy, I got some correct idea.
Maybe google crawling and indexing factors would change.
Wordpress sites have same cases, actually, many seo experts know that latest posts and static pages have not so big differences in wordpress site when your site have a low domain authority and recognition, etc.
As like Stephen Ostermiller and Trich said, you'd better concentrate site contents updating and backlink getting not spam. Good luck!